# How do I retrieve a key of ArrayList<String> from a Hashtable?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, key, hashtable

I basically have a HashTable containing `ArrayList<String>,Boolean`. I need to retrieve the key from the Hashtable. I then need to get the first value from the `ArrayList<String>` which is the key.

I've tried :

```
    Hashtable<ArrayList<String>,Boolean> tableRows = tableRead(); // returns the Hashtable.

    ArrayList<String> IDs = new ArrayList<String>();        

    Iterator it = tableRows.keySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        IDs.add(it.next().get(0));      
    }
```

However, this gives me an error: `cannot find symbol`

```
[javac]   symbol:   method get(int)
[javac]   location: class Object
```

Just to give a functional idea: I basically have an entire DB row as a key in the Hashtable. I need to get back only the ID.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Which symbol can it not find?

Comment: how is your hashTable definition?

Comment: Put a generic argument in your Iterator declaration for the type you want, ie. `Iterator<ArrayList<String>>`.

Comment: Well you are calling `get` on an `Object` which is where the compilation error comes from.

Comment: Made the changes required.

Comment: But I basically need the key, shouldn't doing a get on the iterator retrieve the key?

Comment: @gran_profaci What kind of iterator though? The compiler can't know unless you tell it.

Comment: @gran_profaci check my answer, is not good using list as key

Comment: @gran_profaci it'd be a far better idea to just use the id as key, not the whole row. See my answer.

Comment: Yeah... that's true. I couldn't escape it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared a raw `Iterator`, so its `next()` method will return an `Object`, which has no `get` method.  It is your key, but it's typed as `Object` because your `Iterator` is raw (no generic type parameter).

Use the generic `Iterator` returned from the set of keys.

```
Iterator<ArrayList<String>> it = tableRows.keySet().iterator();
```

Then `it.next()` will return an `ArrayList<String>`, on which you can call `get`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use raw types in your `Iterator`

`Iterator<ArrayList<String>> it = tableRows.keySet().iterator();`

And for recommendation, never use a mutable object as a Key cause you would have unexpected behaviour.

> If an object’s hashCode() value can change based on its state, then we
>   must be careful when using such objects as keys in hash-based
>   collections to ensure that we don’t allow their state to change when
>   they are being used as hash keys. All hash-based collections assume
>   that an object’s hash value does not change while it is in use as a
>   key in the collection. If a key’s hash code were to change while it
>   was in a collection, some unpredictable and confusing consequences
>   could follow. This is usually not a problem in practice — **it is not
>   common practice to use a mutable object like a List as a key in a
>   HashTable**.

If you still want make the String collection unmodifiable in this way.

`List<String> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(myKeyList);`

and use `unmodifiableList` as key.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `ArrayList<String>` as the key to a `Map` is a very, very bad idea. You must never use a mutable object as a key, if by any chance the list changes the key will be invalid - this is a design smell (and a stinky one).

As an alternative, I'd suggest you build an immutable key with the concatenation of the strings in the `ArrayList`, or use an immutable list created with [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) or even better, only use the `id` column, it doesn't make any sense to use the entire row as a key.

Anyway, if you *have to* use an `ArrayList` as key, the following code will fix the problem - and there's no need to explicitly use iterators, an enhanced `for` loop is a much better alternative for iterating over the keys in this case:

```
for (ArrayList<String> al : tableRows.keySet()) {
    IDs.add(al.get(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Hashtable<ArrayList<String>,Boolean> tableRows = new Hashtable<>();
    Set<ArrayList<String>> keys  = tableRows.keySet();
    Iterator<ArrayList<String>> itr = keys.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        itr.next().get(0);
    }
```

Hope this willhelp you.